# C++ inherited parent calling all constructor overloads

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I'm working through [this course on udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-cpp-for-ue4-unit-1/?src=sac&kw=learn+c%2B%2B+for+game+development) and I'm baffled at this output.

The default parent constructor for `Creature()` is called even when I call the constructor through the child's constructor. I've been in JavaScript land the last 8 years so I've seen some wacky stuff, but I'm not sure how I'm accident pull this off.

P.S. I know this isnt pretty code, its for the course.

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <string>;

using namespace std;

class Creature
{
public:
    Creature();
    Creature(string name, float health);

    string Name;
    float Health;
};

class Dragon:public Creature
{
public:
    Dragon();
    Dragon(string name, float health);
};

int main()
{
    Dragon dragon2("Smaug", 100.f);
    cout << "The Dragon's name should be Smaug: " << dragon2.Name << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
 
Creature::Creature(string name, float health)
{
    Name = name;
    Health = health;
    cout << "Creature constructor WITH arguments" << endl;
};

Creature::Creature() 
    : Name("UNAMED"), Health(100.f)
{
    cout << "Creature constructor with NO arguments" << endl;
}

Dragon::Dragon(string name, float health)
{
    Creature(name, health);
    cout << "Dragon constructor WITH arguments" << endl;
}

Dragon::Dragon()
{
    cout << "Dragon Constructor with NO arguments" << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Creature constructor with NO arguments
Creature constructor WITH arguments
Dragon constructor WITH arguments
The Dragon's name should be Smaug: UNAMED
```

I understand (sorta) why and how default constructors would be called, but I expected the output to be:

```
Creature constructor WITH arguments
Dragon constructor WITH arguments
The Dragon's name should be Smaug: Smaug
```

Comment: Your parametrized Dragon constructor should be calling the Creature constructor from the member initialization list, not the body of the constructor.

Comment: Also this doesn't actually have anything to do with multiple inheritance. Multiple inheritance refers to a single class inheriting from multiple different base classes, which `Dragon` does not do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
Dragon::Dragon(string name, float health)
{
    Creature(name, health);
    cout << "Dragon constructor WITH arguments" << endl;
}
```

Well, it is syntactically correct but it is not doing what you think it does. `Creature(name,health);` calls the constructor of `Creature` to create a temporary that lives till the end of that line. You see the default constructor getting called because you do not call the `Creature` constructor for the `Dragon` that is being constructed, hence the `Creature` part of the `Dragon` is default constructed.

To call the base constructor:

```
class Dragon : public Creature
{
public:
    Dragon();
    Dragon(string name, float health) : Creature(name,health) {
        cout << "Dragon constructor WITH arguments" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yup. True story: If I had just watched the next video in the course he went over this same point.

Comment: @JDillon522 I don't think it is possible to learn C++ by watching videos. I don't want to exclude the possibility that there is a good video tutorial, though it would not teach you `using namespace std;` (rather explain [why to avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). I recommend to use a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.